# How to channel data thru Django's URL from third party URL without using redirecting?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What kind of existing options there is to make the client's `GET "myserver://api/download/12345.jpg"` to download from `some_cloudfront_server://files/12345.jpg` without redirecting the client to that CloudFront-path? Ie. I want the client see only `myserver://api/download/12345.jpg` all the time.

It should be some kind channeling solution, as downloading a full file first to Django-server and then sending it to the client is not applicable (takes so much time that the client will see timeout before a response to its query comes). Any existing libraries for this? If I have to create one myself, I welcome even just tips where to start from as Django's communication layer is not too familiar to me.

Problem here is that we are creating CloudFront signatures with wildcards to certain set of files, in format `files/<object_id>*`, thus allowing the client access only to certain object's all files in CloudFront-server directly. This works fine as long as file access traffic from clients is low. But if we start creating separate access signatures for hundred different files at same time, CloudFront starts throttling our requests. Solution I came up is to create and store to Django-server one generic allow-all signature for `files/*`, which is used only by Django-server and never given to any client, and then we let Django-server decide should it fetch files for the client or not. Thus, I can't give to the client the CloudFront-path with a allow-all signature, but I can channel CloudFront-data thru Django's endpoint to the client without showing signature to the client.

Environment I'm working with is Django v1.11, and Django REST Framework v3.4's ViewSets.

Comment: You need to configure your web-server (Nginx / Apache) for this. For instance it seems you should be able to do this using `X-Accel-Redirect`'s (Nginx). Here's a tutorial I found: https://www.mediasuite.co.nz/blog/proxying-s3-downloads-nginx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One colleague heard about my problem and mentioned that signatures can be made locally at server, thus no CloudFront connection needed every time the signature is created and we can keep signatures as file specific. He took this task for himself so I don't know details yet.